# Not loading page content and submitting forms?

Tags: jquery

The following code should load the data of the linked page; then submit the `form[0]` on the page and repeat that every `.2 seconds`; but this code is giving me the error `"SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector."` How do I fix this? I run this code in the google chrome console. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get( "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=1558850&type=robux&expectedPrice=2", function(data) {
            document.html(data);
            document.forms[0].submit();
        });
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Is your url is correct. you are not getting any form in the data.

Comment: Are you sure the request is going through properly and you are receiving the data you want? Try `console.log(data)` inside the `$.get` success. Also `document` has no method `html`.

Comment: You have to log in to have the forms; this is a screenshot of the page: http://imgur.com/SCAvINb.png

Comment: did you try what @AdamMerrifield said? did you check if you get the desired data?

Comment: I tried it; I still get the same error.

Comment: you get error? so data equals error? if so, then there's a problem with the transaction between your page and the given url, not with your code! at least not for the time being

Comment: Every time I run this; or with console.log instead of document.html(data); I get "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector."

Answer (score 0):

You try this... I think document.html(data) is wrong here

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get( "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyPurchase?assetid=1558850&type=robux&expectedPrice=2", function(data) {
            $('body').html(data);
          if(document.forms[0].length)
            document.forms[0].submit();
        });
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: here problem with form. in the above url he is not getting any form

Comment: why you are using setInterval here?

Answer (score 0):

It throws the error because it can't read document as a valid **JQuery element**.
Note that `.html()` is a JQuery method.
`document.write()` is the one you use with document.